# Debug a crash dump from a different machine with different Windows path

Tags: azure, windbg, sos

I have a crash dump from a Windows Azure server. I can't seem to debug it on my local pc (Win 7) because Azure installs windows on D: and my local pc is installed on C:. This seems to have the effect that when I tried to load sos via

```
.loadby sos clr
```

it looks on D rather than C and so does not load SOS.

Is there somewhere I can make it look on my C drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to specify a path, you should use .load rather than .loadby. In your case, `.load c:\<path to sos>\sos.dll`. Make sure that you load the same version of sos.dll as clr.dll being used in your dump. You can find out such details with the `lmv m clr` command.